# Scrollbar in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried many things to do 2 things :

- center my content (horizontal)
- have a scrollbar right and bottom

Here my code :
# encoding: utf8
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

```
class Program:

    def __init__(self):
        # Tk.__init__(self)
        # Fill the content of the window
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.geometry("1080x720")

        self.createFrameWithScrollbar()
        self.content()

    def createFrameWithScrollbar(self):
        # Create a Main Frame
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.window)
        self.mainFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        # Create a canvas
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.mainFrame)
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        # Add a scrobar
        yScrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.mainFrame, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        yScrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        xScrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.mainFrame, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
        xScrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        # Configure the canvas
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yScrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=xScrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all")))

        self.frame = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")

        self.currentFrame = Frame(self.frame)
        self.currentFrame.configure(bg="red")
        self.currentFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def content(self):
        label_title = Label(self.currentFrame, text="Title")
        label_title.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=NSEW)
        label_description = Label(self.currentFrame, text="Title")
        label_description.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=NSEW)
        label_version = Label(self.currentFrame, text="0.2 beta [Novembre 2020]")
        label_version.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=NSEW)


# Lauch the program
app = Program()
app.window.mainloop()
```

So the result is the following :

[image]

So any suggestion ?

The bottom sidebar is so small ! I don't know why.
Are regarding the text, it's not center at all ;(
I want to have it center and changing position if I rezize the window

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should pack the Canvas *after* the two scrollbars.  Currently, it occupies the entire left side of the containing Frame, so everything else is necessarily entirely to the right of it.

Comment: In addition, would recommend using either all `pack` or all `grid` and not to mix geometry managers....unless you are a masochist.

Comment: @jasonharper : I tried but nothing changed

Comment: @AndrewAllaire : thank you for the advice. I'm discovering Tkinter so let's try to use grid. Not sure to be able to find the same thing

Comment: @AndrewAllaire: I nearly always use both `pack` and `grid` in an application. They each have strengths and weaknesses. I think you're more of a masochist if you try to do everything with just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pack` works by allocating space along an entire empty side of the master, so the order of when you call pack matters. When you pack the canvas before packing the scrollbar, the canvas takes up the entire left side from top to bottom.

The simple solution is to pack the scrollbars before you pack the canvas.

```
yScrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
xScrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
```

To make the UI look a bit more professional, `grid` is usually a better choice when laying out scrollbars. With `pack`, either one edge of the horizontal scrollbar will be below the vertical scrollbar, or the edge of the vertical scrollbar will be directly beside the horizontal one. That, or you have to add a little bit of padding so the scrollbars don't seem to overlap.

When I have a scrollable widget, I almost always put it and the one or two scrollbars together in a frame using `grid`. Then, I can treat them all as if they were a single widget when adding them to the rest of the UI.

---

In a comment you ask about how to do it in a grid. You simply need to place the widgets in the appropriate rows and columns, and make sure that the row and column with the scrollable widget has a non-zero weight so any extra space is allocated to it.

```
self.mainFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.mainFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

yScrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
xScrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: Thank you!
Do you have an idea how to do the same with grid ?
I´ve tried but it's not conclusive so far

Comment: else with the solution you gave me, both scrollbar are OK ;) just remain my problem to center the content

Comment: @f42: `grid` is just as easy as `pack`. Just read up on documentation for `grid`, it has everything you need to know.

Comment: Oaldey I tryed but no success. The last frame in the canvas doest take the all space. Others are OK

Comment: I added self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=1000) to get the result expected
Now it's ok the frame is center in the canvas.
If I resize the windows it doesn't work anymore as the width is not rezizing.
If I use an even to resize it, the scrollbar doesn't work after all !

Comment: @f42: you do not need to set the minsize for it to work.

Comment: How can you do without the minsize ? (off topic you had really helpful answers on posts which helped me a lot today so THANK)

Comment: @f42: I edited my answer to show how. It's a combination of using row/column weights, and the use of the `sticky` attribute.

Comment: Perfect ;) Thank you